# chapter ref auto completion

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

I am using Texmaker 4.2 on Windows 7. I want to use auto-completion for chapter references in my thesis. I have included `\label`s in my master document while defining chapters.

Auto-completion in all other features is already working (sections, figures, equations, citations etc.). Just chapter ref completions are not showing.

Comment: I had to do it manually for all chapters. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: same issue, still no solution for this cross auto-completion feature ?

Comment: @maulik, you can find the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318928/save-the-customised-completion .