# Save the customised completion

Tags: texmaker, auto-completion

I would like to save my customised completion (user> customise completion) so that every time I close and re-open texmaker, I don't have to redefine it. How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user completion entries are automatically saved in the `texmaker.ini` file when Texmaker is closed (search `texmaker.ini` for `Editor\UserCompletion=` entries after you close the program). They are *not* saved if Texmaker crashes or you logout, restart or close the PC with Texmaker started.

Comment: Now I understand how this website works :) Indeed, I should have made a comment in place of an answer. Better late than never.

Answer (score 1):

you can find it in windows

c:\Users\ *** \AppData\Roaming\xm1

a file "texmaker.ini"

Comment: Thanks, but I only use Linux :)