# TexMaker: How to "save" user defined tags.

Tags: math-mode, symbols, texmaker

So I want to type commands like \geq_{\alpha} or \leq_{\alpha} into the user section (the bit with the symbol of the person, above PStricks, and below Left/Right).

Fine, but how do I save these commands? I closed texmaker and when I started again, the commands were all gone. It seems dumb to keep typing them in again and again and again.

Comment: The answer to [Save the customised completion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318928/save-the-customised-completion/318971#318971) applies here as well (search `texmaker.ini` for `User\TagList=` entries after you close the program).

Comment: OK thanks, so I just always make sure to close texmaker?

Comment: That's the general idea with *any* program, especially the ones with configurable user settings and where your work is saved in files. You must make sure you saved your work and this is the recommended way to do it.